# Grid inside RecyclerView, which column is left or right

Tags: android, grid, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have 2 column grid inside RecyclerView. I would like to use different margins on items in left column and different margins on items in right column.

Inside method bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) of class RecyclerView.Adapter, how can I know if current item is on left side or right side?

I tried using position argument however sometimes it starts filling items from right side (image below, look at item 5) so it is no use.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the column index through the itemView of the viewHolder.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); 
int position = lp.getSpanIndex();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 column grid inside RecyclerView. I would like to use
>   different margins on items in left column and different margins on
>   items in right column.

what about using different `paddings` for your `RecyclerView`? use different `padding` value for `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`.

Comment: Yes, I thouught about it. But problem is that bindHolderView fires with position=5 and I don't have certainty that it is item on left. Usually adapter gives in new row item from left, but SOMETIMES first is item from right.

Comment: set padding in xml file, you do not need to know which view is going to site on the left or on the right